# how can I use curl_multi_setopt(CURLM *handle, CURLMOPT_SOCKETFUNCTION, socket_callback)

Tags: c, linux, libcurl

I see `curl_multi_setopt(CURLM *handle, CURLMOPT_SOCKETFUNCTION, socket_callback);` in *libcurl* homepage.

I saw the info about the `socket_callback`

```
int socket_callback(CURL *easy,      /* easy handle */
                    curl_socket_t s, /* socket */
                    int what,        /* describes the socket */
                    void *userp,     /* private callback pointer */
                    void *socketp);  /* private socket pointer */
```

where is the variable `curl_socket_t` from in ***libcurl***? The document didn't mention it.

Comment: What are you missing then here ? https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLMOPT_SOCKETFUNCTION.html and https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_socket_action.html

Comment: @marcolz it didn't mentioned where the curl_socket_t is from. That's why I'm so confused. and what's the purpose of curl_socket_t?